# Uniform Convergence and Weierstrass M-test

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

> Find $r$ such that $K(x)=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{r-1}}\sin(nx)$ *does **not** converge uniformly* for $x \in R$.

I tried tackling this problem using the Weistrass M-test to find for which $r$ the above series converges uniformly. I found that it converges uniformly for $r>2$. Therefore, I think that the correct anwser is to say that it does not converge uniformly for $r \in (-\infty, 2]$.

I would be grateful if someone could confirm this result, or could warn me if I am completely wrong about this.

Comment: M-test is only one way implication, so the fact that the series doesn't satisfy M-test conditions for $r\le 2$ doesn't automatically mean they aren't uniformly convergent

Comment: So how would you suggest that I can tackle this problem?

Comment: @user160738 can you elaborate on what you said? I mean can you give me your final answer on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll look at the $r=2$ case. The $r<2$ case will follow similarly.

Exercise: If $F_1, F_2, \dots$ are continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ and $F_N\to F$ uniformly on $\mathbb R,$ then $F_N(x_N) \to F(x)$ whenever $x_N\to x.$

Let $F_N(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{N}(\sin (nx))/n.$ Suppose $F_N \to F$ uniformly on $\mathbb R.$ Then from the above,$ F_N(x_N) \to F(0)=0$ whenever $x_N\to 0.$

Now there is a constant $c>0$ such that $\sin x \ge cx$ for $x\in [0,1].$ Let $x_N=1/N.$ Then

$$\tag 1 F_N(x_N) = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\sin(n/N)}{n} \ge \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{c(n/N)}{n} = c.$$

That's a contradiction and we're done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that 
$$
-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{r-1}}\sin(nx)
$$
does not converge uniformly for $r=2.$  Then your result will be confirmed.

It is well known that 
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sin(nx)
$$
converges for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ but does not converge uniformly.

Let
$$
S_N(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}\sin(nx).
$$
We can show that
\begin{align}
S_N\left(\frac{2\pi}{2N+1}  \right)&=\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin t}{t}dt\approx \frac{\pi}{2}\times 1.17,\\
S_N\left(-\frac{2\pi}{2N+1}  \right)&=\int_0^{-\pi}\frac{\sin t}{t}dt\approx -\frac{\pi}{2}\times 1.17 .
\end{align}
This shows that the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\sin(nx)$ is not uniform.
Search "Gibbs phenomenon".

Comment: Are you confident that this is right answer for this problem? Because @user160738 in the comments above says otherwise. Can someone please give me an answer on this?